# Including js file in spree application

Tags: spree

I was trying to include my slider.js file to spree application but it is not working.
I have looked and found that we must include it manually in all.js file but its not working.

I include in my all.js file:

```
//= require store/spree_core
//= require store/spree_auth
//= require store/spree_api 
//= require store/spree_promo
//= require store/slider.js
```

But i am not sure if the slider.js file is included in all.js file.
Is there any method to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default spree app inlcudes all css files in spreesite/app/assets/stylesheets/store/all.css
by  `*= require_tree .` 
And js files spreesite/app/assets/javascripts/store/all.js the same `*= require_tree .` 
If you need to add stylesheet or js just put the file in spreesite/app/assets/stylesheets/store folder. 
 Spree automatically includes them.

If js file still doesn't work try `rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 1):

There's a decent chance you precompiled your assets. Try clearing them out, using the following:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

Comment: Can you tell me how i can include jquery in spree application.

Comment: thanks for the help... I found what i was looking for. Here is the link http://groups.google.com/group/spree-user/browse_thread/thread/a200e12e74aa6e92