# Adding JS to spree

Tags: spree

This may seem as a simple question, but I've been at it for days!

I'm trying to add external forms of JS to my spree app.

- I've tried adding them in ass links, but they get rejected, because it's not over https
- I've tried copying the code and pasting it to files, that are inside the /app/assets/stylesheets/store/ folder
- I've tried adding all the code (to test it out) into the all.js file

but all methodes have failed.

Can some one explain to me how i can add Tweenmax, Jquery and other forms of JS to my app?

With kind regards,

Salman

ps:

I've checked numerous pages, as:

[Javascript/Jquery not working in Spree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455245/javascript-jquery-not-working-in-spree)

[Adding custom cient-side form validations to Spree frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792252/adding-custom-cient-side-form-validations-to-spree-frontend)

[Including js file in spree application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662116/including-js-file-in-spree-application)

http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/asset.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add Custom JS to spree you have to go to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and add the following line `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( scripts/script.js )`